# How to get previous cell count

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I retrieve the count of the previous cell (inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) of my `UITableView` including other section?

In this case there are six cell before "ok2" cell (the selected cell).
[image]

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean. Do you mean cells on-screen, or total cells in the data model, even if they are not currently on-screen?

Comment: I mean the cells on-screen before the selected cell

Answer (score 0):

Use the table view's `visibleCells` method to get an array of the cells on-screen.

Then map those cells to indexPath values using `indexPathForCell`. Finally, loop through  the array of indexPaths backwards, looking for the current indexPath. Once you find it, all indexPaths closer to the beginning of the array represent on-screen cells that are above the cell you are setting up in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

### EDIT:

Actually, better to use the table view method `indexPathsForVisibleRows`. That will give you your indexPaths in one step.

If you want a single number index for each cell it will be artificial. Cells are numbered by indexPath, where the section number is the most significant value, and then the cells are ordered by row within a section.

If you want a numeric index you could do something like this:

```
let maxRowsPerSection = 100 //Change to reflect the actual max rows/section

let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
let indexValues = indexPaths.map{$0.section * maxRowsPerSection + $0.row}
```

By using a value of 100 for maxRowsPerSection you'd get numbers where the last 2 digits represent the row number, and the hundreds digit and above would represent the section number. If you might have > 100 rows in a section you'd need to increase the value of `maxRowsPerSection`.

Comment: The problem is the section divisor:
`Optional("test")
Optional(0)
Optional("test")
Optional(1)
Optional("test")
Optional(2)
Optional("test")
Optional(3)
Optional("test")
Optional(4)
Optional("ok")
Optional(0)
Optional("ok2")
Optional(1)
Optional("tesrqr")
Optional(0)
Optional("faf")
Optional(1)`

Comment: What is that stuff you put in your comment? And what do you mean "The problem is the section divisor"?

Comment: is that:         `let cells = tableView.visibleCells
        for cell in cells{
            let index = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
            print(index?.row)
        }`

Comment: I want a linear index without section. I hope that you can understand me

Comment: Any index ignoring sections would be artificial.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

hope to help anyone I found an answer:

```
var partialSections = 0;
var i = 0
for (i = 0; i < indexPath.section; i += 1) {

    let rowsInSection = self.tableView(self.tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: i)
    partialSections += rowsInSection;
}
let currentRow = partialSections + indexPath.row;

print(currentRow)
```

Comment: I thought you only wanted to count cells that were currently on-screen? The code you posted would count all cells that appear before the current cell, visible or not.

Comment: And is your only goal to get a count of the cells that appear above? In your comments on my answer it looks like you want some sort of unique cell index for each cell.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you understand me. I don't wanna a sort of unique cell

Comment: "I don't wanna a sort of unique cell". What does that mean?!?